# Статистическая аналитика датасетов

Tags: python, pandas

Кто-то знает что это означает в рамках pandas? В смысле задача стоит провести статистическую аналитику датасетов. Это значит надо вывести dtypes, describe просто и тп? Или что-то еще?

Answer (score 0):

Это значит `"Или что-то еще"`.
Вы сами себе это задание придумали? Если нет, то перед тем, как его задать вам наверняка предварительно объяснили что это такое.

Но если вы проспали эти объяснения -  то оказывается есть Гуугл, который дает ответ на любой вопрос.
Например, что такое `"Статистическая аналитика"`

https://analytikaplus.ru/analiz-dannyh-statisticheskie-metody-issledovaniya/

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/other/descriptive-statistics/

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Описательная_статистика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

и т.д.

А `"рамках pandas"` означает, что ваши данные должны быть изначально представлены (или преобразованы) в виде (скорее всего) DataFrame пакета Pandas. В рамках этого пакета есть очень много функций и методов, которые позволяют повести описательный статистический анализ данных без самостоятельного написания сложных скриптов. В том числе и метод `describe()`, но и не только он. Очевидно от вас и требуют представить ваш датасет в указанном виде а потом применить к нему эти самые методы. Я бы на места вашего преподавателя оценивал не то, как вы `"просто выведете"` нечто в консоль, но и как полно вы опишите данные вашего датафрейма с помощью имеющихся инструментов.